# Помогите нарисовать график для уравнения 4-ой степени (c#)

Tags: c#, диаграммы, график

Добрый день. Помогите нарисовать график для уравнения 4-ой степени (Используя Chart). Корни нашел, а вот при построении, график не правильно строится. Заранее спасибо.

коэфф получаю так :

```
var koef = textBox2.Text.Split(',');
foreach (var inf in koef) coeffs.Add(Convert.ToDouble(inf.Replace(".", ",")));
```

После чего строю график :

```
double equationSolve(double x)
{
double answ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
{
double c = coeffs[i];
if (degree != i)
c *= Math.Pow(x, degree - i);

answ += c;
}
return answ;
}

Plot(){
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalOffset = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineWidth = 3;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 3;
// chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = "";


var xmax = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
var xmin = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = xmax;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = xmin;




xmax++;

for (double j = xmin; j < xmax; j += 1)
{

double yy = equationSolve(j);

chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(j, yy);

}

}
```

Comment: Как, интересно, Вам можно помочь при таких исходных данных? График-шмафик - какие значения игреков Вы ожидаете получить и какие получаете? Какая, собственно, формула? Почему вдруг минус перед `equationSolve`? Может, у Вас коэффициенты в массиве идут не в том порядке, в котором Вы берете степень икса.

Comment: Вот как работает программа http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1703/ff/81f40b58587c.png

Comment: **у Вас коэффициенты в массиве идут не в том порядке, в котором Вы берете степень икса**

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: что исправить? Вы мне хотя бы на один вопрос ответили?

Comment: Тут весь код https://pastebin.com/FP6irGZL

Comment: Коэффициенты получаю так:

var koef = textBox2.Text.Split(',');

foreach (var inf in koef)
coeffs.Add(Convert.ToDouble(inf.Replace(".", ",")));

Comment: @Igor судя по последнему комментарию коэффициенты идут в верном порядке

Comment: @Lolidze возможно. Я не собираюсь продираться сквозь простыни кода, раз автору лень вынести то, что у него не получается, в отдельный пример.

Comment: @Igor Извиняюсь, обновил тему

Comment: @fangry https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: @Igor Корни проверял в онлайн калькуляторе(http://www.mathforyou.net/AnyPowSol.html), всё правильно

Comment: @Igor мне кажется, что в настройках самого чарта надо поиграться

Comment: @Lolidze - что тут играться, если ветви параболы с положительным коэффициентом при максимальной (и к тому же четной) степени х направлены вниз. Тут - играйся, не играйся.

Comment: @Igor он же убрал знак минус, чуть ниже в примере, по идее, ветви будут идти вверх

Comment: Минус я убрал, вот что получилось : http://joxi.ru/nAyJgWBiJQ6erZ Но все же, в калькуляторе график немного не такой: http://joxi.ru/D2PdoM4iORgD23

Comment: f(-0.5)=0.075,  f(0.5)=0.575 - проверяйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте шаг по Х равный `0.1`. Слишком грубый шаг `1` и `SeriesChartType.Spline` приводят к такому визуальному результату.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё правильно.